# Can't execute an AlertDialog in an doInbackground() method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I am having problems executing a AlertDialog on a postexecute(). Throws this exception
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
Alternatively, when I placed the AlertDialog.Builder in, it just didn't work
Pls help.
Also in a case were a wrong password is entered, the process is terminated. How can I call a Toast method in a case were the usename or password is invalid
Below is the code snippet

```
public void Login() {

    // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), pass.getText() + " "
    // +user.getText(),
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    String url = "http://107.20.195.151/mcast_ws/" + "?user="
            + user.getText().toString() + "&password="
            + pass.getText().toString();

    result = getHttpResponse(url);  
}


String result;
private String getHttpResponse(String location) {
    result = "";
    URL url = null;
    Log.d(LOGTAG, " " + "location " + location);
    try {
        url = new URL(location);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, " " + "error" + e.getMessage());
    }
    if (url != null) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            int lineCount = 0;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result += inputLine.trim();
            }

            in.close();
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e(LOGTAG, " " + "IOError " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Internet Access",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, " " + "url" + url);
    }
    return result;
}

class PostToTwitter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Login();
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Success");
        Log.d(LOGTAG, result);
        Log.d(LOGTAG, result.substring(0, 16).trim());
        // Log.d(TweetActivity.getLogtag(),"Successfully Posted: " +
        // params[0]);

        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String msg = "Login successful";

        if (result.substring(0, 16).trim().equals(msg)) {
            // System.out.println(result.substring(0, 16).trim());
            Log.d(LOGTAG, " " + "Connection Test" + result);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure send this SMS?")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //...Attach another thread event to send the sms
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error detected 2");
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            //return  "success";
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            // "Login Succesful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Login UnSuccesful. Check Username or password",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //return null;
        }
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result
        // ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error detected");

        /*
        Intent i = new Intent("com.sms.subsahara.COMPOSESMS");
        startActivity(i);
        //Log.e(LOGTAG, " " + "error2");*/

    }

}
```

On applying the suggestions from Alex, I modified the original code this above, but still get an error.Below is the exception from the logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  326): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(  326): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:472)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at com.sms.subsahara.WebMessengerActivity$PostToTwitter.onPostExecute(WebMessengerActivity.java:216)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at com.sms.subsahara.WebMessengerActivity$PostToTwitter.onPostExecute(WebMessengerActivity.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(  326):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`doInBackground` is not synchronized with the UI thread, which means you cannot directly manipulate UI elements, launch dialogs, etc. from within the method. The fix is easy. Simply move your `AlertDialog` code to the `onPostExecute` method (which *is* synchronized with the UI thread).

When working with `AsyncTask`s, remember that:

1. `doInBackground` is meant to perform the potentially expensive operation (network access, socket connection, database query, etc.)
2. `onPostExecute` is meant to do something with the results, if you wish (this method is synchronized with UI thread, so you can manipulate UI elements directly)

Comment: This guy is spot on.  Only execute processes that must be done independently of the UI Thread in the background.

Comment: but i think you meant "operations", not "processes". ok ok, I know what you mean... but just for the sake of being technical... :P

Comment: Ah yes, I accidentally a word there.

Comment: yeah I know you didn't mean *actual* processes... I'm just being your typical SO-douche bag, know-it-all, recently crowned 10k user. buahah (jk :D)

Comment: thanks. I have done what u suggested, but it still gives errors. I just updated the code snippet, the else statement works fine but the if statement containing the AlertDialog.Builder does noting, and thus I keep getting an error. Pls do help.

Comment: ok well then you'll need to post the relevant error messages in your original post. post the logcat output.

Comment: wait, you still have the `Toast` method in `doInBackground`... toasting involves posting popup messages to the UI so you can't perform this operation in the `doInBackground` method as well. Move it to the `onPostExecute` method (i.e. if the `doInBackground` method returns null, then you can perform the `Toast`... otherwise, show the dialog).

Comment: And by the way... wouldn't you want to show the `AlertDialog` *before* you execute the `AsyncTask`? Why would you perform the HTTP request before hand if the user might end up pressing "no, I don't want to send the SMS"?

Comment: The alert dialog is supposed to be more like a final validation. The app has a flow like this (Write Message -> Choose WebSMS account -> Login -> Verify -> Send using Webservice). Or should I skip the verify phase so as to avoid double HTTP request call and calling another thread to handle that?

Comment: As regards your earlier post on the toast still being in the doInBackground. I have had it removed but it still gives the same errors

Answer (score 3):

DoInBackground() only gets executed on a different thread than the main UI thread. That is the whole point of the AsyncTask.

There are 3 ways to post your results to the UI (pretty much... to the UI Thread)

1. use onPostExecute method. You get the return value of your doInBackground method passed in, and you can do anything with it. (I think this matches your use case.)
2. If your task is on going, and you want little bursts of information on the UI, like a progress bar update, use publishProgress(...) from doInBackground method, which will then be passed in to your onProgressUpdate(...) method in AsyncTask, which will run on the UI Thread.
3. Similar to 2, but you can use RunOnUiThread(...) convenience method to throw a runnable to run in the UI Thread. May not be the prettiest code when you have multiple anonymous methods floating around, but it's for quick and dirty way to do it. NOTE that this method is available on the Activity Class, and not Context class, which may be a deal breaker for some scenarios.

Comment: given that most subclasses of `Context` don't even have a UI, it wouldn't make much sense for it to implement the `runOnUiMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because you Login () is in AsyncTask inside the execution, not in the mainUI inside execution. Can onPostExecute handler out in inside, back to the main thread execution; Also can use in onPostExecute UIThread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                    public void run() {
                    Login();    
                   }
                });
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is correct... but the rest of the answer is totally wrong. (1) `onPostExecute` is run on the UI thread so creating a `Runnable` and executing the code with `runOnUiThread` is just slowing you down, and (2) did you really mean to execute *all* of the `Login` code in `onPostExecute`?? Doesn't this go against the whole purpose of using an `AsyncTask`?!

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Lockwood

`AsyncTask.doInBackground(Void..params)` is *ill suited* for very long and repetitive operations, the better replacement would be a `HandlerThread`.

Reason:

In android 3.2, AsyncTask changed its implementation in a significant way. Starting in Android 3.2, AsyncTask **does not create a thread for each instance in AsyncTask, instead it uses an executor to run background work work for all AsyncTasks on a single background thread!** That means that each AsyncTask thread must run one after another. So, for example, if you have a long AsyncTask thread (image fetcher from a REST), I suggest using a HandlerThread instead, **because the long task running thread could probably delay the whole chain.**

***BUT***

It is possible to *safely run AsyncTask in parallel* by using a *thread pool executor instead*, but I don't know the exact reason, programmers don't recommend doing so, there are couple of reasons behind that which is not relevant to this post. But in case you do this, I would suggest you do your own threading instead, **using handlers to communicate to the main thread when necessary.**